# Runescape Tracker - What do i need to know to make one?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I'm new to the programming world and i'm eager to learn but i've heard that the best way to learn is by having a nice project to work on. And i've always wanted to make a Skill Tracker for my clan. Could you guys give me any advices on what i should learn before being able to start on such a project.

I'm basically looking to make something like: http://runetrack.com/competitions/

I'm familiar with variables, loops, if else statements etc etc. But whenever i try to make a tracker or a simple highscore i get lost because i don't know where to start.

Cheers.

Comment: You would make your program take a username, then access runescape's website to get that character's skill data, read that data from the website and display it in your program's graphical interface. I don't think that runescape provides an api for retrieving character stats so you'd have to do it manually - which means it's probably too complicated/tedious for a first programming project. Start with something a lot smaller.

Comment: Anything you can recommend me starting with?

Comment: After reading the two new answers, turns out there is an api, so it looks like a good project idea.

Comment: Yeah, i should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

Basically Javascript and html for front end development.

Runescape has a rest API for high scores and the GE (http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Grand_Exchange_APIs). You can interact with this API by using AJAX calls.

If you want to host the website, learn how to deploy a simple Apache web server.

Just learn the things I mentioned above: Html, Javascript, AJAX calls (using jQuery) and deploying a simple Apache server. This is more than enough. Along the way you'll pick up other technologies that you might want to use in developing your website.

Answer (score 0):

RuneScape has an api for highscores and the grand exchange. See http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Hiscores_APIs . Example of my character: http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/index_lite.ws?player=aarony . As for what to output it to, I suggest google apps script to get started.

I created my own google site using the above. If you would like to use it for ideas, you can see it here: https://sites.google.com/site/runescapeaarony/